# Mocking an API route in a spy service (with Jasmine)

Tags: angular, typescript, mocking, jasmine, spy

I'm attempting to mock out an API route in a spy service using Jasmine.

I'm very new to Angular, Typescript, and Jasmine, so I can't tell what I'm missing in my code, if I should insert the code within the `beforeEach` or in its own `it('should do xyz...')`, etc.

I *believe* I should be running the mock within `beforeEach`, but I'm running into an error with the payload (see notes below).

**spec.ts**:

```js
providers: [
   { provide: MyService, useValue: CommonServiceSpies.createHttpClientSpy()},
]

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManagerComponent);

    const myVar = TestBed.inject(MyService) as jasmine.SpyObj<MyService>;
    
    const payload = 123 // I'd had an object that resembled the payload from the component.ts file, but it's not working with how the service was set up // Error received was: "Account of type Observable<{}> is not assignable to param of type 'Observable<number>'"

    myVar.GetRemainingAmount.and.returnValue(of(payload)); // Testing window err: "cannot read property 'and' of undefined"

    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

**service.ts:**

```js
export class MyService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    GetRemainingAmount(request: RemainingAmountRequest): Observable<number> {
        return this.http.post<number>('/some-route', request);
    }
```

**manager-component.ts:**

```js
constructor(
    public myService: MyService
  ) { } 

 hasRemainingSpend() : void {
    const payload: RemainingAmountRequest = {
      accountId: this.account.id,
      otherId: this.xyz?.id
    }

    this.myService.GetRemainingAmount(payload).subscribe((response: number) => {
      this.warningSpend = response;

      if (this.warningSpend < this.rate.value || this.warningSpend == null) {
        // call another func
        // this is working as expected
      }
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `CommonServiceSpies.createHttpClientSpy()` does but I can take a guess that it creates an HTTP spy.

[This](https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#testing-components-depending-on-services) is a good resource on Angular unit testing but it also shows you how to mock external dependencies.

I would do:

```
// before the first beforeEach, create a variable that will be a Spy Object
let mockMyService: jasmine.SpyObj<MyService>;
// Inside of the first beforeEach (TestBed.configureTestingModule),
// assign a value to the variable
// The first argument is a string for debugging purposes and the
// the second array of strings are public methods you would like to mock
mockMyService = jasmine.createSpyObj<MyService>('MyService', ['GetRemainingAmount']);
providers: [
   // provide the mock we just created
   { provide: MyService, useValue: mockMyService},
]

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManagerComponent);
    // return an empty object for this method
    myService.GetRemainingAmount.and.returnValue(of({}));
   
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

If you don't want to do that, you can fix what you have by doing the following:

Change this line:

```
myVar.GetRemainingAmount.and.returnValue(of(payload));
```

To:

```
spyOn(myVar, 'GetRemainingAmount').and.returnValue(of({}));
```